# Opening external Url in Django template

Tags: python, django, url, django-templates

I've a Django template like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for url in urls %}
    <li><a href="{{ url.url_name }}">{{ url.url_title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Url is a model that stores Url name and Url title of that particular url. I thought by using this template, I might be able to open the page and get redirected to the external url specified in:

```
<a href="{{ url.url_name }}">
```

Turns out, I can't. How do I achieve this? I'm a newbie in Django and don't know what to do.

Comment: How the generated html code looks like?

Comment: It shows the titles as links but nothing happens when you click them. For example: 

*Title 1
*Title 2
.
.

Comment: @user3504239 please provide what html do you see generated.

Comment: url.url_name is returning the proper url? you can check placing the cursor over the link

Comment: Yes. It is returning the proper url. I checked it by doing what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed url_name is Charfield type, and it is something like example.com or starting with http or https, for all above cases, the below worked for me:

```
<a href="http://{{ url.url_name }}">
```

If you used URL type for the url_name, then your solution should work and your problem is not with  tag.

Answer (score -1):

Please, try with:

```
<a href="{{ url.url_name }}" target="_self">
```

Comment: It's working but only for webpages live on the internet. I just noticed this won't work for webpages saved on my machine. So it will open "http://www.google.com" but I want to open "file:///E:/BEPROJECT/websites_collection/New/www.actors.com/katewinslet.html"

Comment: Please help. I'm stuck

Comment: Oh, you're trying to use local paths. Ok, you can't use full paths ("file:///E:/BEPROJECT/..."). Instead, you should organize your files in certain hierarchy to use relative paths (e.g. websites_collection/New/www.actors.com/katewinslet.html)